# Исходники приложений Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Где можно найти исходники приложения, не очень сложного и не самого простенького, чтобы можно было импортировать в Android Studio и посмотреть как устроено приложение?

Comment: Можно найти, а можно и не найти в гугле и github.

Comment: там же есть примеры приложений, не так ли? Их надо только скачать через саму студию

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

В Android Studio есть коллекция сэмплов. Это, в основном, не полноценные приложения,  а больше устоявшиеся практики, что не уменьшает их полезность для изучения:

*File -> New -> Import Sample*

[image: screen]

появляется мастер следующего вида:

[image: screen]

Здесь вы можете выбрать интересующий сэмпл и он будет автоматически загружен в качестве готового проекта.

Большое количество исходных кодов готовых приложений и отдельных библиотек и классов доступно на *Github* при поиске по интересующим ключевым словам. Например [Галерея изображений](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20gallery&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Wikipedia тоже подсказывает, где найти [open source проекты](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open-source_Android_applications)